# Control of empty fields in a form via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, form

I would like to know if it is safe enough to create via JavaScript control of empty fields. Here is my example in detail:

```
    <script language='javascript'>
        function validate () {
            if(document.getElementById('title').value=="") {
                alert("Enter a Title!");
                return false;
            }
            if(document.getElementById('description').value=="") {
                alert("Enter a Description!");
                return false;
            }
            if(document.getElementById('image').value=="") {
                alert("Inser an Image!");
                return false;
            }
    alert("Success");
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Safe enough for what? What's your threat model? What's your goal? Do you work for a bank or a governmental agency?

Answer (score 1):

It's okay to do the validations in the client side for a better user experience, so the user does not have to wait the response of the server or make a request to know if there is any field that he left incomplete. But you have to do the same validations on the server, because if someone makes a direct request to your server with empty fields, that request is not going through the javascript validations, so your application is going to crash.

Answer (score 0):

You are re-inventing the wheel here. Form fields already have a property called [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input). As the name suggests, it forces a field to be properly filled out before the form can be submitted.

You can use it simply like this:

```
<input type="text" id="title" required />
```

However, if you read the docs, it says that it doesn't work for `type="image"`. I don't know how you are receiving images in your HTML, so I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Another improvement would be to create a single function and provide 2 parameters for field id and name since all of your methods do the same thing.

```
function validateField(fieldId, fieldName) {
    if(document.getElementById('title').value=="") {
        alert("Enter a " + fieldName);
        return false;
    }

    alert("Success");
    return true;
}
```